# VBA Word: Inserting Text Form Fields at a Specified Location

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word, bookmarks

I am new to vba and developing a document that prompts the user to select a variable number of values from a combo box list.  After selecting the values, I want to insert them in order onto the document itself as a Text Form Field.  Let me show you how I generally am trying to get it to work.

First, the user selects values:

```
 [a]
 [b]
 [c]
```

And selects an "OK" button.  Then, I am attempting to add these selected values into the word document starting at a bookmark.  Value "a" should be inserted followed by a space character followed by a blank Text Form Field, followed by two carriage returns.  In the end the result should look something like this:

```
 [bookmark]
 [a]'_'[blank_a]'^p'
 '^p'
 [b]'_'[blank_b]'^p'
 '^p'
 [c]'_'[blank_c]'^p'
 '^p'
```

Where [bookmark] is an invisible bookmark, '_' is a space, and '^p' is a carriage return.  Currently my code is as follows:

```
 Dim myRange As Range
 Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("START").Range.Start, _
 End:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("END").Range.End)

 For i = 1 To NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES
     Selection.FormFields.Add(myRange, wdFieldFormTextInput).Name = "question_" & i
     Selection.FormFields.Add(myRange, wdFieldFormTextInput).Result = "response_" & i
 Next i
```

Naturally, there are no insertions of literal spaces or carriage returns yet as I have not figured out how to do it.  The result of this code is as follows:

```
 [START][blank_c][c][blank_b][b][blank_a][a][END]
```

I would like this order reversed and for there to be the aforementioned formatting inserted.  Any pointers on how to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Well now I feel silly for asking the question. The solution was pretty simple.

```
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("START").Select

 For i = 1 To NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES
     Selection.Font.Size = 11
     Selection.Font.Bold = True
     Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput) _
         .Name = "question_" & i
     Selection.Font.Bold = False
     Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
     Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput) _
         .Name = "response_" & i
     Selection.TypeParagraph
     Selection.TypeParagraph
 Next i
```

So the real issue was placing the cursor in the right location:

```
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("START").Select
```

From there I was able to use Selection to insert the desired FormFields and characters.

[This link was pretty helpful.](http://www.rosetech.in/word_vba_examples.html)

And if you are reading this because you also are new and trying to learn what to do, [check out how to record a macro.](http://www.howstuffworks.com/how-to-create-macro-in-word.htm)  It's a good first step. Record the macro, view the code it generated, and use that code to guide your own development. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I have missed something, but why not relying on simple paragraphs instead on Bookmarks? Here you have a code doing what you want and any other thing (you can modify the ranges of the paragraphs to perform as complex actions as you wish).

```
Dim curRange As Range
Dim start_i As Integer
Dim end_i As Integer
Dim NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES As Integer
NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES = 3
start_i = NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES + 1 '0
end_i = 1 'NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES

Set curParagraph = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.First

curParagraph.Range.Text = "[START]"
i = start_i
Do
    If (start_i < end_i) Then
        i = i + 1
    Else
        i = i - 1
    End If

    Set curParagraph = curParagraph.Range.Paragraphs.Add
    curParagraph.Range.Text = "[question_" & i & "][" & "response_" & i & "]"
Loop While (i <> end_i)

Set curParagraph = curParagraph.Range.Paragraphs.Add
curParagraph.Range.Text = "[END]"
```

Comment: Well... I guess that my solution is not required anymore. In any case, I continue thinking that paragraphs give you more control over the situation.